# Wiremock does not receive any requests

Tags: spring, integration-testing, resteasy, wiremock

I am writing an integrationtest for a resource (Jax-rs with resteasy) which invokes a thirdparty request to the Trustpilot Api to get a review link for a product.
In my tests I wanted to mock this call by using Wiremock and invoke the request by using resteasy Dispatcher.
The code below shows my Setup (names etc are changed).

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { MyResourceTestContext.class })
public class MyResourceIntegrationTest {


    @Rule
    public WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule(wireMockConfig().dynamicPort().dynamicHttpsPort());

    @Autowired
    private MyResource myResource;

    private Dispatcher dispatcher;
    private MockHttpResponse response;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        dispatcher = MockDispatcherFactory.createDispatcher();
        dispatcher.getRegistry().addSingletonResource(myResource);
        response = new MockHttpResponse();
    }

    @Test
    public void testResourceShouldReturnRedirectToTrustpilotreview() throws Exception {

        URI apiRequestURI = UriBuilder
                .fromUri("https://api.trustpilot.com/v1/private/product-reviews/business-units"
                        + "/{businessUnitId}}/invitation-links")
                .build(BUSINESS_UNIT_ID);

        URI expectedRedirectURI = UriBuilder.fromUri("https://products.trustpilot.com/#evaluate/{reviewLinkId}")
                .build(REVIEW_LINK_ID);

        stubFor(post(apiRequestURI.toString())
                .willReturn(okJson("{\"reviewLinkId\":\"" + REVIEW_LINK_ID + "\","
                        + "\"reviewUrl\":\"" + expectedRedirectURI.toString() + "\"}")));

        MockHttpRequest request = MockHttpRequest.get("/myResource");
        dispatcher.invoke(request, response);

        WireMock.verify(1, postRequestedFor(urlEqualTo(apiRequestURI.toString())));
        Assert.assertEquals(HttpStatus.TEMPORARY_REDIRECT.value(), response.getStatus());
        Assert.assertEquals(expectedRedirectURI.toString(), response.getOutputHeaders().getFirst("Location"));

    }
```

But what I'm getting is (with my actual bid in the url):

```
com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.VerificationException: Expected at least one request matching: {
      "url" : "https://api.trustpilot.com/v1/private/product-reviews/business-units/<bid>/invitation-links",
      "method" : "POST"
    }
    Requests received: [ ]
```

Stepping into the request with the Debugger I can say this request and other requests are actually executed successfully. But they are not recognized/mocked by Wiremock.

Is there something wrong with my Wiremock setup? Any Ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of reasons why this isn't sending anything to WireMock at the moment:

1. WireMock only accepts relative URLs when stubbing so passing the full URL including protocol and domain won't work. Try something equivalent to `stubFor(post(urlPathEqualTo("/v1/private/product-reviews/business-units/<bid>/invitation-links")` instead.
2. There doesn't seem to be any way for your class under test to know which host/port WireMock is running on and no forward proxying set up so the code is presumably still trying to call the real Trustpilot API.

To solve 2. you have a couple of options:

1. Set up your class/code under test to use `localhost` as the destination host and the result of `wireMockRule.port()` as the port number, or `wireMockRule.httpsPort()` if you're on HTTPS.
2. Use the new [auto JVM proxy setup](http://wiremock.org/docs/multi-domain-mocking/#configuring-for-junit-4x) feature to proxy your app's calls through WireMock. This assumes you're on WireMock 2.31.0+ and that your app's HTTP client respects the JVM proxy system properties.

Comment: That's it. It's working now, thank you very much.