# WireMock doesn't receive the HTTP request issued by HTTP client

Tags: java, spring-boot, integration-testing, integration, wiremock

I am writing integration test to mock external local service called **dates-service-svc**  which actually runs on port 8081 . I am using wireMock to mock the service and HTTP client to issue a request to **dates-services-svc** , but the requests issued by HTTP client doesn't hit the wireMock . and raises an "connection refused " exception  .
when the test case finish its execution . the logs says

> Requests received: [ ]

On the other hand ,I issued the request using the post man . wireMock replies with that **The requested URL matches the stub registered**

I configured the wireMock as following

```
@Rule
    public WireMockRule wireMockServer = new WireMockRule(new WireMockConfiguration().port(8084)
            .notifier(new ConsoleNotifier(true)));
```

```
@Before
    public void setUp() {
        wireMockServer.start();
        WireMock.configureFor("localhost", 8084);
    }
```

```
    @AfterEach
    public void afterEach() {
        wireMockServer.resetAll();
    }

    @After
    public void tearUp() {
        wireMockServer.stop();
    }
```

I created very simple test cases to just test whether WireMock works fine or not .here it is

```
 @Test
    public  void testWireMock()
    {
        try {

            configureFor("localhost", 8084);
            stubFor(any(urlEqualTo("/v1/service1/local-dates/"))
                    .willReturn(aResponse().withStatus(200).withBody("hello wireMOck")));;
         
            String datesEndPoint = "https://dates-service-svc/v1/service1/local-dates/";
      HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder()
                    .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1)
                    .followRedirects(HttpClient.Redirect.NORMAL)
                    .connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(20))
                    .build();
            URI uri = new URIBuilder(paymentDatesEndPoint)     
                    .build();
            HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                    .GET()
                    .uri(uri)
                    .build();
            HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
            List<ServeEvent> allServeEvents = getAllServeEvents();
            List<LoggedRequest> requests = findAll(getRequestedFor(urlMatching("/v1/.*")));
            verify(getRequestedFor(urlEqualTo("/v1/service1/local-dates/")));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Assertions.fail(e);
//            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

logs

> 021-10-07 14:01:57.710 Verbose logging enabled 2021-10-07 14:01:57.861
> INFO 7407 --- [           main] wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.util.log
> : Logging initialized @22479ms to
> wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog 2021-10-07 14:01:58.034
> INFO 7407 --- [           main] w.org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server
> : jetty-9.4.30.v20200611; built: 2020-06-11T12:34:51.929Z; git:
> 271836e4c1f4612f12b7bb13ef5a92a927634b0d; jvm 11.0.12+8-LTS-237
> 2021-10-07 14:01:58.050  INFO 7407 --- [           main]
> w.o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler    : Started
> w.o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@47e2a158{/__admin,null,AVAILABLE}
> 2021-10-07 14:01:58.057  INFO 7407 --- [           main]
> w.o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler    : Started
> w.o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@65dce54c{/,null,AVAILABLE} 2021-10-07
> 14:01:58.076  INFO 7407 --- [           main]
> w.o.e.jetty.server.AbstractConnector     : Started
> NetworkTrafficServerConnector@61186191{HTTP/1.1,
> (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8084} 2021-10-07 14:01:58.076  INFO 7407 --- [
> main] w.org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server        : Started @22695ms
> 2021-10-07 14:01:58.875  INFO 7407 --- [p1096402541-143]
> w.o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler.__admin       : RequestHandlerClass from
> context returned
> com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.http.AdminRequestHandler. Normalized
> mapped under returned 'null' 2021-10-07 14:01:58.897 Admin request
> received:
> 127.0.0.1 - POST /mappings
>
> Connection: [keep-alive] User-Agent: [Apache-HttpClient/4.5.12
> (Java/11.0.12)] Host: [localhost:8084] Content-Length: [264]
> Content-Type: [text/plain; charset=UTF-8] {   "id" :
> "e149540c-33bf-4b39-8d56-5653fb77cdd9",   "request" : {
> "url" : "/v1/service1/local-dates/",
> "method" : "ANY"   },   "response" : {
> "status" : 200,
> "body" : "hello wireMOck"   },   "uuid" : "e149540c-33bf-4b39-8d56-5653fb77cdd9" }
>
> 2021-10-07 14:01:59.141  INFO 7407 --- [           main]
> w.o.e.jetty.server.AbstractConnector     : Stopped
> NetworkTrafficServerConnector@61186191{HTTP/1.1,
> (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8084} 2021-10-07 14:01:59.142  INFO 7407 --- [
> main] w.o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler    : Stopped
> w.o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@65dce54c{/,null,UNAVAILABLE}
> 2021-10-07 14:01:59.143  INFO 7407 --- [           main]
> w.o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler    : Stopped
> w.o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@47e2a158{/__admin,null,UNAVAILABLE}
>
> org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError   at
> org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.fail(AssertionUtils.java:47)     at
> org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.fail(Assertions.java:140)    at
> com.sympl.txn.handler.TxnHandlerControllerIntegrationTests.testWireMock(TxnHandlerControllerIntegrationTests.java:229)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at
> org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
> at
> org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
> at
> org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
> at
> org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
> at
> org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
> at
> org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
> at
> com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.junit.WireMockRule$1.evaluate(WireMockRule.java:79)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)    at
> org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)  at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)   at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)     at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)   at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)  at
> org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)    at
> org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
> at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)   at
> com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
> at
> com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
> at
> com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
> at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException  at
> java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl.send(HttpClientImpl.java:561)
> at
> java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientFacade.send(HttpClientFacade.java:119)
> at
> com.sympl.txn.handler.TxnHandlerControllerIntegrationTests.testWireMock(TxnHandlerControllerIntegrationTests.java:222)
> ... 34 more Caused by: java.net.ConnectException    at
> java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.Utils.toConnectException(Utils.java:971)
> at
> java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.PlainHttpConnection.connectAsync(PlainHttpConnection.java:179)
> at
> java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.AsyncSSLConnection.connectAsync(AsyncSSLConnection.java:56)
> at
> java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Http1Exchange.sendHeadersAsync(Http1Exchange.java:237)
> at
> java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Exchange.lambda$responseAsyncImpl0$8(Exchange.java:435)
> at
> java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Exchange.checkFor407(Exchange.java:367)
> at
> java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Exchange.lambda$responseAsyncImpl0$9(Exchange.java:439)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniHandle(CompletableFuture.java:930)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniHandleStage(CompletableFuture.java:946)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.handle(CompletableFuture.java:2266)
> at
> java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Exchange.responseAsyncImpl0(Exchange.java:439)
> at
> java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Exchange.responseAsyncImpl(Exchange.java:343)
> at
> java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Exchange.responseAsync(Exchange.java:335)
> at
> java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.MultiExchange.responseAsyncImpl(MultiExchange.java:347)
> at
> java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.MultiExchange.lambda$responseAsyncImpl$7(MultiExchange.java:384)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniHandle(CompletableFuture.java:930)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniHandleStage(CompletableFuture.java:946)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.handle(CompletableFuture.java:2266)
> at
> java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.MultiExchange.responseAsyncImpl(MultiExchange.java:374)
> at
> java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.MultiExchange.lambda$responseAsync0$2(MultiExchange.java:293)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:1072)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1705)
> at
> java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl$DelegatingExecutor.execute(HttpClientImpl.java:153)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeAsync(CompletableFuture.java:2591)
> at
> java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.MultiExchange.responseAsync(MultiExchange.java:246)
> at
> java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl.sendAsync(HttpClientImpl.java:632)
> at
> java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl.send(HttpClientImpl.java:540)
> ... 36 more Caused by: java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException
> at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Net.java:130)  at
> java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:675)
> at
> java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.PlainHttpConnection.lambda$connectAsync$0(PlainHttpConnection.java:165)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
> Method)   at
> java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.PlainHttpConnection.connectAsync(PlainHttpConnection.java:167)
> ... 62 more

I tried the solutions below:

- The solution proposed by @P.Raber in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69116881/wiremock-does-not-receive-any-requests)
- I used `WireMockServer` instead of `WireMockRule`
- I removed ConfigureFor() and put it again
- I configured the wirkmock to start on the same port as the external local service runs (this would sound so dump but I am running out of solutions ) ; however this also  made no difference . it still fails

Comment: Just a guess but your test is reaching out to dates-service-svc and your mock is listening on localhost?

Comment: yes , I think the mock is listening on the localwhereas  the HTTP client is trying to send the request to actual data-service-svc . the request suppose to pass by the WireMock server and returned the mocked response , but this is not case

Comment: @Byron as I mentioned , I issued the request from the post man using *http://localhost:8084//__admin/{requestURL} and I received a reply from WireMock